# How to find folder ID by path in Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm able to find a Google Drive Folder's ID by searching its name, but how can I find the Folder ID by searching its path?

I'm searching within a Drive that has multiple folders with the same name, but different paths, so I want to ensure I'm finding the correct folder ID.

```
results = service.files().list(q="name='folder_name'",
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
        supportsAllDrives=True, driveId='driveId', includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, corpora='drive').execute()
```

The above returns multiple folders. I don't see a query parameter for the path.

Sample folder structure:

```
Food
   \Vegetables
      \Folder 1
        Item 1
        Item 2
        Item 3
      \Folder 2
        Item 1
   \Fruit
      \Folder 1
   \Protein
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample folder structure for confirming your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike updated, thanks.

Comment: No, in this scenario, I want to retrieve just the Folder ID of `Folder 1` in `Vegetables`. But I only see a way to query  `name='Folder 1'` which also returns the Folder ID for the `Folder 1` in `Fruit` which I don't want

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your updated question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly retrieving the files and folders in the specific folder using the folder name. So in your case, it is required to use a workaround.

#### Workaround:

I would like to propose the workaround as follows.

From your sample folder structure, I could understand that you want to retrieve the file list under the folders of `Folder 1` and `Folder 2` in `Vegetables`. In this case, how about using the following search query?

```
q="name='Folder 1' and '### folderId of Vegetables ###' in parents"
```

In this case, please retrieve the folder ID of `Vegetables`. By above modified search query, the folder ID of `Folder 1` in the folder of `Vegetables` can be retrieved.

Of course, you can also retrieve the folder ID of `Vegetables` using the script.

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already been able to get the file metadata using Drive API.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)